# Учебное задание по созданию простой crud программы, используя servlet, jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet, web-apps

При выполнении задания захотелось поексперементировать с очень интересной ситуацией, когда -> пользователь вводит данные в форму -> нажимает на кнопку "создать" -> (данные записываются в базу данных) -> пользователь после нажатия на кнопку видит на этой же странице те данные которые находятся в базе данных (все) и только что добавленную запись.

У меня получилось все кроме одного нюанса, после нажатия на кнопку данные добавляются в базу данных но пользователю только что введенные данные не отображаются, а отображаются они после еще одного нажатия на кнопку "создать" или добавления новой записи.

Наверное, может я и не прав, предполагаю, что ответ пользователю (отображение страницы с данными) приходит быстрее чем запись попадает в базу данных и только после следующего добавления видно предыдущую запись.

Так как же сделать так чтобы данные моментально отображались пользователю и были реальными (те, которые реально находятся в БД, а не подмену списком (list) перед добавлением в БД, чтобы имитировать быстрое добавление). Прошу помочь с данной ситуацией.

**Данные которые выводятся пользователю в JSP файле**

```
<body>
<div>
    <div class="form">
        <%!private static final UserStore userStore = UserStore.getInstance();%>
        <%
            CopyOnWriteArrayList<User> storeResult = UserStore.getInstance().getResult();
            if (!storeResult.isEmpty()) {
                for (User user : storeResult) {
                    %>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <b>Name:</b> <%=user.getName()%><br>
                        <b>Login:</b> <%=user.getLogin()%><br>
                        <b>Date:</b> <%=user.getCreateDate()%><br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <%}
            } else {%>
                <pre>
                    <b>Can't find any users</b>
                </pre>
            <%}%>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
```

**Стартовая страница тоже JSP файл**

```
<body>
<div class="mainBlock">
    <div>
        <form action="insert" method="POST">
            <label for="userName">Name</label>
            <input id = "userName" type="text" name="user" placeholder="User name"><br>
            <label for="userLogin">Login</label>
            <input id = "userLogin" type="text" name="login"  placeholder="User login"><br>
            <label for="userEmail">Email</label>
            <input id = "userEmail" type="email" name="email"  placeholder="User email"><br>
            <label for="userPassword">Password</label>
            <input id = "userPassword" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="User password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="create">
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="center">
        <form class="inline" action="result" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="get users" name="getUsers">
        </form>
        <form class="inline" action="update" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="update user" name="updateUser">
        </form>
        <form class="inline" action="delete" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="delete user" name="deleteUser">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <br>
        <jsp:include page="get.jsp" flush="true"/>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

**Сервлет insert**

```
public class InsertServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersServlet.class.getName());
    private static UserStore userStore;

    /**
     * Get UserStore object to manipulate with database.
     * @throws ServletException exp.
     */
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        userStore = UserStore.getInstance();
    }

    /**
     * doPost method insert data to database.
     * @param req request.
     * @param resp response.
     * @throws ServletException servlet exception.
     * @throws IOException input output exception.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.insertIfNotEmpty(req, resp);

    }

    /**
     * Create User instance with received value from the request and insert to the database.
     * @param req request.
     * @param resp response.
     * @throws ServletException servlet exception.
     * @throws IOException input output exception.
     */
    private void insertIfNotEmpty(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user;
        if (!req.getParameter("user").equals("") && !req.getParameter("login").equals("")
                && !req.getParameter("password").equals("") && !req.getParameter("email").equals("")) {
            user = new User(req.getParameter("user"),
                    req.getParameter("login"), req.getParameter("password"), req.getParameter("email"));

            LOG.debug("Add user to database with name {} and login {}", user.getName(), user.getLogin());
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/forms/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            userStore.insert(user);
        }
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/forms/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }


}
```

Comment: Мне кажется что я нашел ошибку. Наверное нужно поменять 2 строчки местами.

     req.getRequestDispatcher("/forms/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
     userStore.insert(user);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Просто поменял местами 2 строчки

```
userStore.insert(user);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/forms/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Сначала запись в БД, а потом отправка юзеру страницы с селектом всех пользователей в БД.

А если стояла задача,- "Показать стартовую страницу", то наверное было бы так как при постановке вопроса, сначала показываем страницу а за спиной добавляем, что бы юзер не заметил времени которое БД тратит на добавление данных. Наверное для маленького количества данных этого нет смысла делать, но все же.